# Mongodb connect timed out with type unknown

Tags: mongodb

I try to use prisma to connect to mongodb, but I got error like this:

Error: MongoDB error
Server selection timeout: No available servers. Topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [ { Address: 9.218.111.60:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: timed out }, ] }

It works when I am using other database

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you use to attempt MongoDB server connection.

Comment: _"It works when I am using other database"_  What works?  What database?

Comment: Perhaps the firewall blocks it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.